# Redux update react component when store updates

Tags: redux, react-redux

In pure React I can pass props to child component and it re-renders. I would like to have the same functionality in Redux as well.

I want to have a component that is connected to Redux store and whenever the store updates (ideally select elements in store), the component is re-rendered (thus not directly dispatching an action). How can I achieve this in Redux?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [React-Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) library provides this capability, with a method called `connect` that generates store-connected wrapper components.  Please see the [Usage with React](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) section in the Redux docs.

Answer (score 3):

**Why do so few read the docs?**

If you did, you'd find that
Redux creator Dan Abramov provides a great introduction into Redux with his [**Getting started with Redux**](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) video tutorials linked from the [Redux GitHub page](https://github.com/reactjs/redux).

Videos 24-26  (there are 30 in total, averaging 3 minutes a piece) Dan does a great job of explaining what you are asking for.

I'd recommend watching the whole series from the start because it provides a great foundation about the inner workings of Redux that are a useful lead up to the use of the (helper) library React-Redux in the later videos.